# Integration by substitution of $\int 1/\sqrt{x(1-x)}\, dx$

Tags: integration, substitution

Find $$\int \frac {1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx$$ using the the substitution $x=\sin^2(u)$

Comment: what are your efforts?

Comment: So, when you use the substitution, as suggested, what does $dx$ equal?  What is the integrand after substitution?  This is child's play.  If I have an integral $\int (x+1)\,dx$, and was told to substitute $x+1 = u$, then $dx = du$, and then fill in the blanks $$\int (\underbrace{\underline{\;\;\;\;}}_{x+1 = u})\; (\underbrace{\underline{\;\;\;}}_{dx = du})$$, what is the result?  Surprise! $$\int u\,du$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x = \sin^{2}(u)$ then $dx = 2\sin(u)\cos(u)\,du$, so the integral becomes:
\begin{align*} \int \dfrac{2\sin(u)\cos(u)du}{\sqrt{\sin^2(u)(1-\sin^2(u))}} &= 2 \int \dfrac{\sin(u)\cos(u)\,du}{\sqrt{\sin^{2}(u)\cos^{2}(u)}} \\ &= 2 \int \dfrac{\sin(u)\cos(u)du}{\sin(u)\cos(u)} \\ &= 2 \int \,du \\ &= 2u +C \\ &= 2\arcsin(\sqrt{x}) + C \end{align*}

Comment: I think there is a mistake with your last step.  $x= \sin^2(u)$ doesn't mean $u=\sin^2(x)$ ..

Comment: Yeah, good catch.

Comment: The substitution should be, more properly, $u=\arcsin\sqrt{x}$, so it's clear that $0<u<\pi/2$ and so both $\sin u$ and $\cos u$ are positive in the stated interval.

Comment: Should it also be + or -  √x ?

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**

With the substitution $x= \sin^2(u),$ we have $dx = 2 \sin(u) \cos(u) \ du$ Figure out the transformed integrand.

Comment: I don't understand why I got downvoted.. I just offered a helpful hint...

Comment: I did too.  Here (+1) to helo